# Minimum distance between given array and an all-coprime array

Tags: arrays, numbers, primes, mathematical-optimization

We have the following problem:

Let's call a sequence of numbers `b[1]...b[n]` ***fancy*** if `gcd(b[i], b[j]) = 1` for all `1 <= i < j <= n.` (Meaning all the elements of the array are coprime to each other).

Given a sequence of numbers `a[1], a[2], ..., a[n],` what is the minimum possible value of `abs(a[1]-b[1]) + abs(a[2]-b[2]) + ... + abs(a[n]-b[n])`, where `b[1]...b[n]` is a fancy sequence?

EXAMPLE:

**Input** - [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
**Output** - 0
**Explanation**: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] itself is a "fancy" sequence, so the minimum possible distance is 0.

**Input** - [1, 6, 4, 2, 8]
**Output** - 3
**Explanation** - One of the optimal "fancy" sequences is [1, 5, 3, 1, 8].
`distance([1, 6, 4, 2, 8], [1, 5, 3, 1, 8])` = |1-1| + |6-5| + |4-3| + |2-1| + |8-8| = 3.

**Input** - [1, 2, 4]
**Output** - 1
**Explanation** - Zero distance is impossible because [1, 2, 4] is not "fancy".
One of the optimal "fancy" sequences is [1, 2, 3].
`distance([1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3])` = |1-1| + |2-2| + |4-3| = 1.

***Constraints***

`1 ≤ n ≤ 10^2` [Size of the array]
`1 ≤ arr[i] ≤ 30` [Meaning the input array can have elements with values in this range]

I am completly out of ideas on this one.
How can we solve this in the most optimal way?

Comment: One method is to first try all distance 0 sequences that are fancy, then all distance 1 sequences that are fancy, and so on. This guarantees minimality, but it may or may not be the most efficient.